# Cython not installed. Please install cython from

Tags: python, cython

I installed RADAR tool (for Rapid Automatic Detection and Alignment of Repeats in protein sequences.).
RADAR requires Cython for setup. I installed cython, If i want to instal RADAR, I got the below message :

print """Cython not installed. Please install cython from http://cython.org."

It seems that i did not installed cython despite I installed it using pip.

Python 3.9.12 is installed. Os is mac Ventura 13.2

Any help is appreciated.

When I installed cython it is installed in /Users/mac/opt/miniconda3/bin/cython.  Is it ok Or should I installed it in another directory.

Comment: You have probably more than one Python installation on your system. This kind of problem is common for example when using Jupyter notebooks because Jupyter often comes with its own Python installation. Long story short: you must install Cython in the Python installation that will be used by RADAR.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  I checked which python i installed. I have python and python3 (Is  there any problem with this? If yes how do I remove it?). :)

Comment: There is no problem in having multiple Python installations. I currently have 3 different versions on my box to allow version dependant tests. But you have to know which version is used and make sure you install the dependencies there. Calling the `python` program with its absolute path is generally a robust way to make sure of which one is used...